# How to safely extend my Ubuntu partition without losing any data?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gparted

I'm trying to figure out the way to extend my partition without losing any data. I've created a video to explain my problem.

https://d.pr/v/Sc7lpX

Answer (score 2):

From the information provided in your question, extending a partition alone is always safe. Moving and shrinking other partitions may be unsafe, however, because of small amounts of fragmentation that naturally occur.

In order to [determine the rate of fragmentation](https://superuser.com/questions/474536/in-linux-how-do-you-check-if-a-disk-is-fragmented), you can use `sudo fsck -fn /dev/sdXn` on your partition even when it is mounted as the **`-n` option makes no changes**.

```
291595/1222992 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 1927790/4882432 blocks
```

If the amount of non-contiguous is too close to ~1%, you may damage or permanently lose data when shrinking (or possibly moving) the filesystem. `fsck` will tell you the total number of files (first number in `x/y`), for 300,000 files even 1% non-contiguous is 3,000 files that might be important to you or the operating system.

---

From your video: you will need to use an external Live USB (preferably one with GParted on it, like Ubuntu Live USB or [Slax](https://www.slax.org/)) in order to move Linux's partitions around as this can't (shouldn't...) be done while the system is running.

Your Linux installation is inside an extended partition, which is a virtual partition table (Logical Volume Management) that allows an [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) to have more than 4 partitions. This *shouldn't* prevent you from increasing the size of the extended partition / Linux partition with the unallocated space from outside the LVM.

At a later time I can try to study the video closely and give exact steps or `fdisk` commands to partition your disk, but hopefully this can give you a starting point.

Here are some other questions you might have overlooked when asking:

[How do I resize a partition in Ubuntu linux without losing data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/how-do-i-resize-a-partition-in-ubuntu-linux-without-losing-data?rq=1)

[How to reduce and remove Physical Volume from active Logical Volume?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153712/how-to-reduce-and-remove-physical-volume-from-active-logical-volume?rq=1)